# What is the most efficient keyvalue pair for ordering?

Tags: c#

Since I cannot order my dictionary, what is the best way of going about taking key value pairs and also maintaing an index?

Comment: Could you be more specific ? What are you trying to do exactly ?

Comment: i have a dictionary that i am passing to a method that needs the keys to be in a specific order to process properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be more specific about the requirements:

- Do you still need to be able to look up by key efficiently?
- Should it just maintain the insertion order (1st, 2nd etc), or allow arbitrary insertion points?
- Do you want to allow duplicate keys?

I suspect that maintaining a `List<TKey>` or `LinkedList<TKey>` along with a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` will be the best/simplest route if you still need to look them up - otherwise a 
`List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` would work fine.

For the first option, you could encapsulate this in a type implementing `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`. You may actually want to make it a `LinkedList<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` and a `Dictionary<TKey, LinkedListNode<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>>` to make it efficient to iterate over keys, values or entries, and to be able to handle removals efficiently.

Comment: I needed insertion order maintained. Before reading this I had decided to create an ordered List<> and send it in parallel with the IDictionary<>.  Is there any performance benefit to linking the lists as you suggest?

Comment: @zsharp: Using a LinkedList makes removal and replacement more efficient, basically - that's all. It may be worth you implementing it just with `List<T>` first (which will probably be simpler) and then optimising it if it becomes a bottleneck.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at `System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary` and `System.collections.Generic.SortedList`.

Sorted dictionary orders the pairs, sorted list orders the keys and values independently.

Comment: i tried sorteddictionary, but then i cant put a custom order, it sorts by alphabetical.

Comment: You need to implement IComparable on your objects, which will give you a custom sort.

Comment: @Spence: That assumes there's a comparison based purely on the objects which will accomplish the desired effect. Now we know it's insertion order which is important, SortedList/SortedDictionary definitely aren't the way to go.

Comment: I was offering an alternative to the question asked.  Now we have more information, it gets more interesting.  I certainly agree that if his insertion order is important then List or LinkedList are the way to go in this case.  His question seemed to infer that you couldn't sort a dictionary which is why I directed him to the two classes.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
KeyValuePair<object, object>[] objects;
```